# What's the likelihood function? Lactose intolerant exercise

Tags: bayesian, bayes-theorem

It's an exercise from [Bayes Rules! An Introduction to Bayesian Modeling with R](https://www.bayesrulesbook.com/chapter-2.html#exercises-1).

> Lactose intolerance is an inability to digest milk, often resulting in an upset stomach. Fatima wants to learn more about the proportion of adults who are lactose intolerant, $\pi$. Her prior model for $\pi$ is:

| $\pi$ | 0.4 | 0.5 | 0.6 | 0.7 | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $f(\pi)$ | 0.1 | 0.2 | 0.44 | 0.26 | 1 |

> Fatima surveys a random sample of 80 adults and 47 are lactose intolerant.

How to calculate the likelihood in order to figure out the posterior model?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d-mp3nW51W4

Answer (score 2):

> Fatima surveys a random sample of 80 adults and 47 are lactose intolerant.

Reading the observation's results, the likelihood is proportional to

$$l(\mathbf{x}|\pi)\propto\pi^{47}\cdot(1-\pi)^{33}$$

thus, conditional to the parameter values, we have that the likelihood is

$$\begin{cases}
l(\mathbf{x}|\pi=0.4)\propto 0.4^{47}\cdot 0.6^{33} \\ 
l(\mathbf{x}|\pi=0.5)\propto 0.5^{80}\\ 
l(\mathbf{x}|\pi=0.6)\propto 0.6^{47}\cdot 0.4^{33}\\
l(\mathbf{x}|\pi=0.7)\propto 0.7^{47}\cdot 0.3^{33}
\end{cases}
$$

thus the posterior is

$$\begin{cases}
p(\pi=0.4|\mathbf{x})\propto 0.1\cdot0.4^{47}\cdot 0.6^{33} \\ 
p(\pi=0.5|\mathbf{x})\propto 0.2\cdot0.5^{80}\\
p(\pi=0.6|\mathbf{x})\propto 0.44\cdot0.6^{47}\cdot 0.4^{33}\\
p(\pi=0.7|\mathbf{x})\propto 0.26\cdot0.7^{47}\cdot 0.3^{33}
\end{cases}
$$

Normalizing we get the desired posterior which is

| $\pi|\mathbf{x}$ | 0.4 | 0.5 | 0.6 | 0.7 | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $p$ | 0.001 | 0.114 | 0.834 | 0.052 | 1 |

---

the posterior normalization is calculated as follows

$$\frac{0.1\cdot0.4^{47}\cdot 0.6^{33}}{0.1\cdot0.4^{47}\cdot 0.6^{33}+ 0.2\cdot0.5^{80}+0.44\cdot0.6^{47}\cdot 0.4^{33}+0.26\cdot0.7^{47}\cdot 0.3^{33}}\approx 0.001$$

---

This is the drawing of Prior VS Posterior

[image]

As you can see, after data observations, the pmf is more concentrated around the mean

Answer (score 1):

Put $A = \{ $ 47 are intolerant and 33 are not  $\}$.

$$P( A| \pi = p) = \binom{80}{33}p^{47}(1-p)^{33} $$
Hence we know $P( A| \pi = p)$ for all four values of $p$.

By Bayes' theorem,
$$P(\pi= p | A) = \frac{  P( A| \pi = p) f(p) }{ \sum_j P( A| \pi = p_j) f(p_j) }$$

Comment: as per text data, 47 are intolerant and 37 tolerant

Comment: N: after your edit, you likelihood looks still wrong... $\pi=p$ is the proportion of adults who are lactose intolerant

Comment: @tommik, yes, thank you!